# Option chosen from dropdown is not retained - Sonata Admin

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

When I submit the form. The value chosen from the dropdown list is successfully saved in the database.

The issue is when form is refresh in the edit mode, the **value chosen for the brand** is not retained.

Here is my configureFormFields:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{

    $formMapper
        ->add('image', 'text')
        ->add('brand', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => Brand::class,
            'choice_label' => 'slug',
        ))
        ->add('Page', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'choices'  => array(
                'Homepage' => 'Homepage',
                'HomeProduit' => 'Home Produit',
                'HomeRubrique' => 'Home Rubrique',
                'PageContent' => 'Page Content'
            )))
    ;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue.

The problem was that there was no relationship between the 2 tables (relationship added and everything works fine). Hope that can help someone some day.